# Getting a users DOMAIN/username from a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I am doing a school project however don't understand this (yet)

i pretend get the user id from a domain.
i have a simple web application to field with contacts and storage on access. so far all good.

however i can't figure who manage with my research. 
It happens that I have stored all the data but don't know to which user belongs so the ideal is getting the user name of the person who is currently logged on to the Windows operating system.

I found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

but my main question is, what do I do with this research? where copy+paste? in default.aspx.cs or default.aspx or web.config?

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no Copy&Paste for Authentication. You have to get your head around this.

Then we need your environment to know. As Windows User i assume your are talking about Active Directory. And with 'simple web application' you mean ASP.net or?

Here is [a tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650307.aspx) from MSDN for Forms Authentication with Active Directory .

And here is [a tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(VS.98).aspx) for Intranet Application with ASP.net MVC. It shows how to setup your `web.config`, enable NTML and using `Context.User.Identity.Name` in development.

Comment: of course, and i not pretend someone do the work for me otherwise how i can understand and learn?
what i want to know is where to applie my research... on which file? i have 3 (more of course) default.aspx.cs or default.aspx or web.config

Comment: `web.config` is the main settings and configuration file for an ASP.NET web application. Here change your authentication mode. And for the rest you have to build a `Login.aspx` Page.

Comment: It's everything explained, step by step here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650307.aspx

Comment: i don't use login.aspx
my ideia is dispose in the intranet: the person open the link and then i can record in my database the person who open the link through user domain

Comment: Something like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(VS.98).aspx

Comment: hmm i will look up this help. I already have the web application working. 
the user field the text box and it saves on access database.. however i don't know who answer. i pretend save the user id in database. how can i show you my work?